# MySQL subquery on multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to retrieve names and address of all guests with bookings for a hotel in London, alphabetically ordered by name in MySQL using subqueries and getting this Error:

```
Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

Here's the query that I run:

```
select * from guest 
where guest_no = 
    (
        select guest_no 
        from booking 
        where hotel_no = (select hotel_no
                          from hotel
                          where city = 'London')
    );
```

and here's the schema for hotel, booking and guest:

```
hotel (hotel_no, hotel_name, city)

booking (hotel_no, guest_no, date_from, date_to, room_no)

guest (guest_no, g_name, g_address)
```

additionally, here's the schema for room:

```
room (room_no, hotel_no, type, price)
```

Please help me with the above mentioned error and possible solutions.

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not use join as

```
select
g.guest_no,
g.g_name,
g.g_address
from guest g
inner join booking b on b.guest_no = g.guest_no
inner join hotel h on h.hotel_no = b.hotel_no
where h.city = 'London'
```

Comment: fastest gun in the west

Answer (score 0):

When you use '=', it means that the result of your subquery is exactly 1 row. If you expect multiple results, you need to use the `IN` keyword, like so:

```
select * from guest where guest_no IN (select guest_no from booking where hotel_no IN (select hotel_no from hotel where city = 'London'));
```

EDIT: As @flaschenpost mentions, the performance could be degraded in case there is no proper indexing on the columns involved in the subqueries. You would probably do well to use `JOIN` rather than such nested subqueries.

Comment: Be a bit careful with the speed, there have been examples where `WHERE IN` with a subselect uses no index.

Comment: Oh, yes, that's a good point! I will edit my answer to add this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change you query to

```
select * from guest 
where guest_no IN 
               (select guest_no from booking where hotel_no 
  IN (select hotel_no from hotel where city = 'London'));
```

Answer (score 0):

you need joins !

try this !

```
select a.g_name,a.g_address from guest a inner join booking b on a.guest_no=b.guest_number inner join hotel h on b.hotel_no=h.hotel_no inner join rooms r on b.room_no=h.room_no
where h.city='London'
```